# using preg_match multiple times?

Tags: preg-match

I'm trying to modify a line in PHP that deals with data that comes from XML.
The php make this data usable by a streamer media player.
here my problem, this line:

```
if (($title <> "") && (strpos($link,"<") === false) && preg_match("/Chi/i",$lang))
```

is sorting only the Chinese streams, but the XML has more streams I want, these streams has "music" in their $lang (currently rejected and that's fine) **but** with the string "China" in their $title.

How can I add another condition to the above line that will gives me all the relevant streams (but not irrelevant streams, like "music" from "India")

Answer (score 0):

Use [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) rather than preg_match in that case. You can simply mix some conditions like that:

```
if (($title <> "") && (strpos($link,"<") === false) && (stripos('chi', $lang) !== false || stripos('indi', $lang) !== false))
```

Or put china in one array, and india in another. And when you done just print whole table in some order.

Comment: Tnx, but I do not understand your answer. If i changed it a bit: (stripos('music', $lang) || stripos('china', $title) and add it to the line above I'm getting error.

Comment: My fault, I have forgotten about one `)` at the end and `!== false`.